# which gems for asynhronous HTTP-request processing exists?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, multiprocessing, httpclient, asynchronous

I'm writing diploma project and have a problem with sending two HTTP request and recieving answers.
Of cause I can process data consistently, but it will be more fester and effectively to make, send and recieve HTTP-requests asynchronously.

I know that in this situation the best answer is to use Fibers and EventMashine ([em-http-request](https://github.com/igrigorik/em-http-request)),
or I can use some ruby HTTP-client with multithreading...

But diploma project must contain a сhapter with review of existing instruments. So I need to compare em-http-request with some other libraries and choose the best option.

So question is: 
which ruby-gems for asynhronous HTTP-requst processing exists now?
( em-http-request analogs )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a good talk about it here (look down for the slides):

http://lanyrd.com/2012/rubyconf/szpth/

The person giving the talk also has a comparison of all the ruby http clients, which indicates their concurrency model:

http://bit.ly/RubyHTTPClients

Comment: It's GREAT!!!!! Thanks! @Nitrodist, how about libraries, which can do few requests intime ( some gems for asynchrounous processing )?

Comment: I found columns "sync", "parallel", "async", "pipelining". It's exactly what I'm looking for!! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

The most relevant gem that I have found for handling asynchronous HTTP requests is Typheous. You can find more information on the gem [here on github](https://github.com/typhoeus/typhoeus) or [here on rubydoc.info](http://rubydoc.info/gems/typhoeus/0.6.6/frames)

Comment: thanks! I know that http-client Faraday supports Typhoeus adapter, and   EventMachine, Patron, Excon, Net::HTTP adapters too.